# Convert values to TRUE/FALSE

Tags: sql

I have a SQL field that has values >=0. I would like to create a Field (or display this field) as True (if value >0) and False (if value = 0).

Comment: You may use a trigger to achieve that, but your question should be better explained

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: @guisantogui -- a trigger?  are you trolling?

Comment: @Hogan Now I think I understood what was asked, a trigger does not make any sense endeed

Answer (score 0):

For simple data conversion tasks you can use the CASE construct -- this is similar to an if statement in other languages:

```
CASE WHEN value = 0 THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END AS my_new_field
```

Comment: Sorry - new to SQL - where would I put this line? After the SELECT portion and before the WHERE?

Comment: @B.Clapper -   This would be in the select portion where you have the fields instead of a "standard" field.  You should read a book on SQL this is basic stuff.